# How do I match "abc?def?" but not "abc??def?"

Tags: regex

I am trying the following:

```
.+\?[^\?].+\?
```

That is, match everything til a "?", then, if no other "?" after that, match everything til another "?". I guess it is not working because the first .+ matches the entire string already.

Comment: so the first (and second) "everything" can also include question marks?

Comment: Hm no, but it wont happen (but would be cool to guard against that, too). I have to avoid the double mark case because "a??" happens but it is another thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description isn't precise, but here's the rules I assume you need your regex to satisfy:

1. Zero or more characters that are not '?'
2. A '?'
3. One or more characters that are not '?'
4. A '?'

This is actually pretty simple.

```
[^?]*\?[^?]+\?
```

Note that this will match a substring of a larger string. If you need to ensure the entire string exactly matches this, throw in `^` and `$` anchors:

```
^[^?]*\?[^?]+\?$
```

---

Explanation:

1. `^`

   Start of the string. In a multiline context this also matches start of the line, but you're probably not in a multiline context.
2. `[^?]`

   Match anything that's not the literal character '`?`'.
3. `*`

   Match zero or more of the previous token.
4. `\?`

   Match a literal '`?`'.
5. `[^?]`

   Match anything that's not the literal character '`?`'.
6. `+`

   Match one or more of the previous token. This ensures that you cannot have two '`?`' in a row.
7. `\?`

   Match a literal '`?`'.
8. `$`

   Match the end of the string (or the end of the line in a multiline context).

---

Note: I assumed zero or more non-'`?`' before the first '`?`'. This will match something like `?abc?`. If this is illegal, change the first `*` to a `+`.

Comment: Very simple indeed. Not sure why the other way wouldnt work too. I realized you didnt put a \ before the ? on [^?]. Maybe thats why. Thank you!

Comment: This looks good to me. If you want to explicitly match letters then it is a bit different, but this is a good post either way. A good thing to note is that formally specifying what you want to match, as Kevin does at the beginning, can go a long way towards helping you write your regex.

Comment: @Dokkat: Inside a character class (the `[]` thing) most special characters are no longer special and thus should not be escaped.

Comment: I see, that makes sense now. I was, then, matching for "not \?" which is why I was getting all matches. What matters is it working now so thank you.

Comment: @Dokkat: I think your real problem was the `.+`. This could match the `abcd?`, then the `\?` would match the *second* `?`.